# insert variable via forEach into regex expression

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, ecmascript-6, frontend

As you can see below, I'm trying to count how many times a character in string J occurs in string S.  The only issue is I can't put the argument o in the forEach loop into the regex expression as shown in the console.log.

```
var numJewelsInStones = function(J, S) {
    let jArr = J.split('');
    let sArr = S.split('');

    jArr.forEach(o=>{
    console.log(S.replace(/[^o]/g,"").length);      
    })
};

numJewelsInStones("aA", "aAAbbbb");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create regular expression with constructor function where you pass string parameters:

```
new RegExp('[^' + o + ']', 'g')
```

Your replace logic might look like:

```
S.replace(new RegExp('[^' + o + ']', 'g'), '')
```